# syntax error, unexpected |=, expecting '}'

Tags: jq

I want to build a json with jq filter, the usecase is very simple,

I have a json file as this,

```sh
# cat input.json
{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}
```

and I want to generate a json file with jq as follow,

output:
increase the value of foo,

```json
[
  {
    "leafCalls": {
      "text": 43
    }
  }
]
```

and the filter I am using is defined as this,

```sh
# cat results.jq
[.[] | . as { foo: $leafText,  bar: $leafCode} | {
    leafCall: {
      text: $leafText
    },
  } | {
    leafCalls: .leafCall |= . + 1
}]
```

But there is a syntax issue as said below,

```sh
# <input.json jq  --slurp --from-file results.jq > output.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected |=, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 6:
    leafCalls: .leafCall |= . + 1
jq: 1 compile error
```

Beside, there is also a problem if want to concat a string to the value of "bar",

For what I want is,

```
[
  {
    "leafCalls": {
      "text": "less interesting data string"
    }
  }
]
```

The filter is

```
# cat results2.jq
[.[] | . as { foo: $leafText,  bar: $leafCode} | {
    leafCall: {
      text: $leafCode },
  } | {
    leafCalls: .leafCall + " " + "string"
}]
```

and the jq is saying,

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting '}'
```

Can anyone tell what's the problem with the filter definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first output, increase the value directly. Parentheses are needed for precedence.

```
jq '[. as { foo: $leafText } | {
    leafCalls: {
      text: ($leafText + 1)
    },
  }
]' input.json
```

And similarly for the string:

```
jq '[ . as { foo: $leafText,  bar: $leafCode}
    | { leafCalls: { text: ($leafCode + " string" ) } } ]
    ' input.json
```

Comment: This works! thank you @choroba for the answer. Could you pls take a look on another issue on the jq if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869690/how-to-append-a-object-to-a-array