# How to append a object to a array?

Tags: jq

I have a input json file as this,

```json
{
  "foo":[
     "key1",
     "key2"
   ],
  "bar": "key3"

}
```

Here is how the jq filter defined,

```sh
[.[] | . as { foo: $names,  bar: $name} | {
    names: [ $names | range(0;length) as $i | {
        key: ($names[$i])
    }],
  } | {
    values: .names,
}]
```

This will generate a json file as this,

```sh
<input.json jq  --slurp --from-file concat.jq > output.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "key1"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to append the `key3` to the output json and define the filter as this,

```
[.[] | . as { foo: $names,  bar: $name} | {
    names: [ $names | range(0;length) as $i | {
        key: ($names[$i])
    }] |= .+ {key: $name},
  } | {
    values: .names,
}]
```

This seems doesn't work,

```sh
<input.json jq  --slurp --from-file concat.jq > output.json
```

result to below exceptions,

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected |=, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 4:
    }] |= .+ {key: $name},
jq: 1 compile error
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this achieve what you wanted :

```
q --slurp '[
    .[] | . as { foo: $names,  bar: $name} |
    {
        names: ([
            $names | range(0;length) as $i |
            { key: ($names[$i]) }
        ] + [{ key: $name }])
    } |
    {
    values: .names,
    }
]' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use `map` and build the objects directly?

```sh
<input.json jq --slurp 'map({values: (.foo + [.bar] | map({key:.}))})'
```

```json
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "key1"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2"
      },
      {
        "key": "key3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FhDH_swAvJ)

Comment: thanks @pmf, I must get the output with the below command, ```<input.json jq  --slurp --from-file concat.jq > output.json``` I cannot change this which means I need to manage this in the `concat.jq`.

Comment: Then save the filter `map({values: (.foo + [.bar] | map({key:.}))})` as `concat.jq`.

Comment: sadly,  current implementation need to iterator over each element, `map` should work for this sample but doesn't solve my problem. :(